# Django, user can update email and username but not Image

Tags: html, django

As in title I have a problem with updating form because everything works as I want but not an image updating feature.It sends success message but it does not change the image for the profile.

views.py

```
def profileView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user,)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile-page')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
    'u_form': u_form, 
    'p_form': p_form}
    return render(request, 'shop/profile.html', context)
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    {{ user.username }}
    <img src="{{ user.profile.user_image.url }}">
    <a href="{% url 'delete-page' pk=user.id %}">Delete</a>
    <form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{ p_form.as_p}}
        {{ u_form.username }}
        {{ u_form.email }}
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def profile_creation(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
        {{ u_form.email }}
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you share forms classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send files in a form, you specify the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to encode images in the POST request:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ p_form.as_p}}
    {{ u_form.username }}
    {{ u_form.email }}
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```